# MATLAB : reading data file "HAVING TITLE"

Tags: matlab

I want to read data file that includes titles and want to fit regression models to describe relationship between the variables `X` and `Y`.

The data file, `data.txt`, has two columns named `X` and `Y` and the data are

```
 X=[32.0 48.5 36.3 42.9 36.5 32.6 34.0 38.4 27.1 27.6 48.4 43.5 38.5 23.7 34.3 28.7 24.1 38.5 44.6 42.7 47.6 20.6 25.8 37.3 30.3 28.8 28.6 23.9 41.2 21.9 45.2]

 Y=[45.8 75.8 52.8 70.1 56.4 51.1 48.6 55.8 45.9 45.3 69.9 63.9 60.8 37.1 52.9 47.1 42.3 56.3 70.0 70.8 71.5 30.1 41.1 57.8 48.0 46.4 46.9 38.0 68.3 32.0 68.0]
```

I tried to read this by the following commands :

```
 fid = fopen('data.txt','r');
 dt = fread(fid);
 fclose(fid);

 dt
```

but i am not understanding the result it showing.

EDIT:

The structure of the data file is like the following :

```
  X     Y
 32    45.8
 48.5  75.8
36.3   52.8
42.9   70.1
36.5   56.4
```

Comment: try [`dlmread`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/dlmread.html).

Comment: @sgar91 I have tried dlmread('data1.txt') But it's occurring error
`??? Error using ==> textscan
Mismatch between file and format string.
Trouble reading number from file (row 1, field 1) ==> X Y\n

Error in ==> dlmread at 125
    cresult  = textscan(fid,'',nrows,'headerlines',r,'headercolumns',c,...`

Comment: Can you show the format of your data file explicitly?

Comment: @EitanT I have edited my question showing the format of the data file.

Answer (score 0):

if your data file is like:

```
32.0, 45.8
48.5, 75.8
...
```

then you can read it as follows:

```
data = load('file_name.txt');
x = data(:, 1); y = data(:, 2);
```

Comment: I have variable name in my data. so `data = load('data1.txt')`
`??? Error using ==> load
Unknown text on line number 1 of ASCII file G:\r save file\data1.txt
"X".`Kindly see my edit.

>>